# Find joint probability function

Tags: probability

There is a problem which I think I'm not realizing well.

Distribute $n$ different balls in $n$ cells, where each cell has its number and can store multiple balls.

Let $X$ be the number of balls in the first cell. Let $Y$ be the number of balls in the second cell.
We need to find a joint probability function of $P\{X=i\}$ and $P\{Y=j\}$.

My attempt was to think about this problem in a combinatorical way. Say we have a total of $n^n$ ways to distribute the balls. After we put $i$ balls in the first cell and $j$ balls in the second cell, we are left with distribution of $n-i-j$ balls in $(n-2)$ cells. Thus, $P\{X=i, Y=j\}=\cfrac{(n-2)^{n-i-j}}{n^n}$

I was told that the right way to find this function is to use the known function of multinomial distribution. But I couldn't realize it immediately while thinking about my way of solving. If the distribution is multinomial, it means that $X,Y$ are not independent. Is there any way to solve this problem using combinatorics? Or just stick to multinomial distribution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $n \gt 2; \ i + j \le n$,

There are ${n \choose i}$ ways to choose $i$ balls for the first bin and ${n-i \choose j}$ ways to choose $j$ balls for the second bin and then $(n-2)^{n-i-j}$ ways to place remaining $(n-i-j)$ balls in rest $(n-2)$ bins.

So,

$$P\{X=i, Y=j\}=\cfrac{{n \choose i} {n-i \choose j}(n-2)^{n-i-j}}{n^n}$$